# "double" fibre product

Tags: category-theory, pullback

A (*1*-)fibre product (*a.k.a.* pullback) in a category consists of three distinct objects:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X \times_Z Y @>q>> Y \\
@VpVV @VVV \\
X @>>> Z
\end{CD}$$

$(X \times_{Z}Y,p,q)$.

Now, in particular we have (often) non-trivial fibre products over the same objects, *i.e.* $X=Y$, this particular fibre products can be indicated as $X \times_Z X \rightrightarrows X$.

If I want to repeat the operation of fibre product considering $X \times_Z X \times_Z X$ how many arrows associated with this fibre product will I have?I have to take count of the two arrows **within** the first fibre product, so I think that the question is not trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd leave this as a comment, but I want to draw a couple of diagrams...

Suppose you have three arrows $f,g,h\colon X\to Z$ (possibly $f=g=h$, if you are interested in a "fibered cube" of the same object over $Z$). Then you may consider first the pullback with respect to $f$ and $g$:

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
X\times_Z X @>\overline{f}>> X\\
@VV\overline{g}V @VVgV\\
X @>f>> Z
\end{CD}$$

And then consider the pullback

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
(X\times_Z X) \times_Z X @>k>> X\\
@VV\overline{h}V @VVhV\\
X\times_Z X @>g\overline{f} = f\overline{g}>> Z
\end{CD}$$

This gives you *three* arrows:

\begin{align*}
(X\times_Z X)\times_Z X & \xrightarrow{k} X,\\
(X\times_Z X)\times_Z X & \xrightarrow{\overline{h}} X\times_Z X \xrightarrow{\overline{f}} X,\\
(X\times_Z X)\times_Z X & \xrightarrow{\overline{h}} X\times_Z X \xrightarrow{\overline{g}} X.
\end{align*}

In general, $\underbrace{X\times_Z \cdots \times_Z X}_n$ should come with $n$ arrows to $X$.

Is that what you need?